# Sharpening (5%, 10%, 15%)

Tags: vb.net, image, image-processing

I want to do **sharpening** on an image (like 10% , 5% and 15%). Can anyone provide information or code in Visual Basic.NET how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking out the excellent AForge image library.

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/c5a43907-302d-3d0d-1ab1-a39b9d0f7013.htm